# how to add properties file in Unity Testing Scripts

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, unity-test-tools

I am currently writing automation test script for android application that is built in Unity. So I have some game objects that I want to test and see. But the details related to that particular object like what it should display and all I need to specify in code and then i will validate them. I am wondering is there any way that I could store them in a .property file or something and i can retrieve the required data from there.

Comment: Hi there! What have you attempted so far? I see no reason why this should be unfeasible using the File class in the `System.IO` namespace

Comment: but you see in android we generally do with a property file in asset folder. I am looking for something similar here. I know that File class can be used. But i need to do additional parsing to get my values.